# postgres + how to delete the password for hive metastore and set new password

Tags: linux, postgresql, hive, ambari, hdp

we are working on HDP 2.6.5 cluster with ambari

we want to change the password for hive , since we think we enter previously wrong password

also from hive log we get:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "hive"
```

so we try

```
# su - postgres
Last login: Mon Aug 31 15:27:30 UTC 2020 on pts/2
-bash-4.2$ psql
psql (9.2.24)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# CREATE DATABASE hive;
ERROR:  database "hive" already exists
postgres=# CREATE USER hive WITH PASSWORD 'something';
ERROR:  role "hive" already exists
```

but as we can see above we get - 'ERROR:  role "hive" already exists"

how to delete the current password and set the new password?

reference - https://community.pivotal.io/s/article/How-to-find-the-Hive-metadata-store-password?language=en_US

Comment: You alter role with password and set the new password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need to delete the old password and there isn’t really a way to delete it. Just use alter role command.

```
Alter role test with password ‘something’;
```

Comment: do you mean to really type - "Alter role test with password ‘something’;" ??

Comment: Replace the role name with yours and password with what you want.